# Alternative of ClientLoginTokens

Tags: google-ads-api

I am working on google Adwords API to upgrade our code for migration from v201302 to v201309.
Any one can suggest me, what code we should use in place of following code ( as ClientLoginTokens now deprecated).

```
String clientLoginToken = new ClientLoginTokens.Builder()
                    .forApi(ClientLoginTokens.Api.ADWORDS)
                    .withEmailAndPassword(configurations.get("email"), configurations.get("password"))
                    .build()
                    .requestToken();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps that I took to get OAuth2 working. YMMV of course...

**Step 1 - Register Application with Google Console API**

1. Log into Google using your email and password above
2. Head to the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). You probably get redirected to Google Cloud Console
3. Under 'APIs & Auth' click on 'Consent screen'. Fill in at least 'Product Name' and 'Email'.
4. Under 'APIs & Auth' click on 'Registered apps'.
5. Click 'Register App'. Fill in details ensuring that you select 'Native' as platform.
6. Under 'OAuth 2.0 Client ID' make a note of the CLIENT ID and CLIENT SECRET values.

**Step 2 - Generate Refresh Token**

Next step is to generate a refresh token. This is a generate-once-use-multiple-times token that allows your application to obtain new access tokens:

1. Download [GetRefreshToken.java](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/source/browse/examples/dfp_axis/src/main/java/dfp/axis/auth/GetRefreshToken.java).
2. Create an `aps.properties` file to be referenced by the `GoogleClientSecretsBuilder()
         .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)` call. This `ads.properties` file should contain two lines:

   *api.adwords.clientId=client-id-from-step1.6*

   *api.adwords.clientSecret=client-secret-from-step1.6*
3. Using web browser log into the Google AdWords MCC.
4. Run `GetRefreshToken.java` and follow instructions i.e. copy browser URL into browser, enter code returned into console etc. etc.
5. You should now have a refreshToken. Copy this refresh token into your `ads.properties` files like this:

*api.adwords.refreshToken=your-refresh-token*

PS `GetRefreshToken.java` has a couple of dependencies. If you are using Maven then here they are (adjust versions accordingly!):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev50-1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
        <artifactId>adwords-axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Step 3 - Generate Credential**

With your refreshToken, clientId & clientSecret in your `ads.properties` you can now generate a Credential like this:

```
Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
    .forApi(Api.ADWORDS)
    .fromFile()
    .build()
    .generateCredential();
```

**Step 4 - Get AdWords Session**

The final step (hats off to you if you have got this far!) is to create an AdWords Session using the `oAuth2Credential` instance of `Credential` that you created in Step 3. You can do this by adding two more things into your ads.properties file:

*api.adwords.developerToken=developer-token-from-mcc*

*api.adwords.clientCustomerId=client-id-of-adwords-account-that-you-want-to-access*

Then get an AdWords session up using like this:

```
AdWordsSession awSession =
                new AdWordsSession.Builder()
                .fromFile()
                .withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
                .build();
```

**Step 5 - Grab a coffee and reflect on how easy it is to access the Google AdWords API using OAuth2**

This step is entirely optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can not transform your old process identical as before. There are some examples in the [Migration Guide](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/wiki/MigrationGuide) from Google. See the Authentication/OAuth 2.0 section:

```
If you are coming from using ClientLogin, we've added a few features to make it extremely easy to switch over.

Once you've generated a refresh token using the GetRefreshToken.java example of your examples download, and you've copied it into your ads.properties file, you'll be able to create a refreshable token with the OfflineCredentials utility.

Credential oAuth2Credential = new OfflineCredentials.Builder()
.forApi(Api.DFP)
.fromFile()
.build()
.generateCredential();

Once authorized, you can set the Credential object into the builder or session:

DfpSession session = new DfpSession.Builder()
.fromFile()
.withOAuth2Credential(oAuth2Credential)
.build();

OAuth2 will now be used when making API calls.
```

You might change Api.DFP to Api.ADWORDS. OAuth 2.0 at Google is fully covered in the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) article.

Comment: Thanks Dag ..What i should use in place of client id and secret.can we use adword customer id in place of client id.